# bashrc volume changes do not always work

Tags: 18.04, sound, bashrc, surface

I've just installed Ubuntu on my SP3 and I have no regrets. I just have a few problems that I'd like to fix. My problem is with the volume and I made the following changes to my `bashrc` file based on the recommendations online:

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 200%
```

And it worked but here was the problem.  Whenever I hit the volume down button to decrease the volume, it wouldn't go back up to this level and then fluctuations in the volume level would begin.

It seems like these changes aren't as permanent as I thought they would've been.  But of course, it could just be a matter of my own inexperience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes done it .bashrc are not permanent. This file is sourced (loaded) only when you open your terminal.

If you want to set it up every time you log in you can create simple bash script:

```
editor ~/set_sink_volume.sh
```

and paste:

```
#!/bin/bash

pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 200%
```

Remember to add permissions to be able to execute this script:

```
chmod u+x ~/set_sink_volume.sh
```

Then go to `Applications Menu` -> `Startup applications`

Add new item with:

- Name: `Set sink volume`
- Command: `~/set_sink_volume.sh`.

And that's it.

Alternatively you can add startup item manualy through terminal:

```
editor ~/.config/autostart/set_sink_volume.sh.desktop
```

Then paste and save this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=~/set_sink_volume.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[pl_PL]=Set sink volume
Name=Set sink volume
Comment[pl_PL]=Set sink volume
Comment=Set sink volume
```

Comment: Nothing changed tho.  Once I bring the volume down, I'm not able to bring it back up to 200

Comment: You're looking for over-amplification option. I'm not sure about older versions of Ubuntu, but it should be avilable in `System Settings` -> `Sound`. https://imgur.com/a/J9fKCgL

Comment: I'm using 18.04